Pixel width and heigth of *.mrr files
I have converted raster files from BIL file format to MRR (MapInfo Multi Resolution Raster) file format with MapInfo Pro. The BIL files have size 2500 x 2500 pixels and pixel resolution of 2 meters. The Raster Info tool of MapInfo shows that MRR files have size of 3072x3072 pixels and pixel resolution of 2 meters.
Does anyone know why MRR files have so bigger width and height values ?

Posting a screen shot of your conversion parameters would be helpful.  Posting a screenshot of the before and after data would be helpful.  Maybe the 2500x2500 is the data area and the remainder of the 3072 are NoData values?

According to this support article (which I think should be included in the main documentation):

MRR format stores data in tiles and default tile size is 1024. Whenever
Pro converts any legacy raster format data to MRR format, output MRR
height and width will be calculated on the basis of how many tiles
required in the x and y direction to accommodate the input raster
size.

The minimum number of 1024x1024 tiles your 2500x2500 raster will fit into is 3x3 so your output size will be 3072x3072 (3x1024 x 3x1024).


Thank you for your meaningful answer

Here is the answer:

Many remote sensors return data that is at varying resolutions. For
example, the WorldView2 satellite simultaneously records data at 0.31m
cell size as well as 1.24m and 3.72m. MRR can efficiently store raster
data such as this by using fields with different cell sizes.

Source:
https://customer.precisely.com/s/article/MRR-Multi-Resolution-Raster-Revolutionizing-Raster?language=en_US#:~:text=Structure%20of%20MRR&text=The%20MRR%20file%20will%20contain,a%20particular%2C%20user%20designated%20type.

There's only a single cell size (2m) and it doesn't change between input BIL and output MRR according to the question.
